# Linux shell script getting "stuck" during network interface reset

Tags: networking, scripts, network-manager

I'm working on a linux shell script to aid in resetting network devices on my system is a bit speedier way than typing 5 commands.  The problem is that the script gets intermittently stuck and returns an error stating the device is "busy". There is no logical reason why i should be getting this message?  Can someone take a look at this nd point me to where I've gone wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if script is being run as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Please run this script with sudo."
    exit 1
fi

# Function to check if a device is in monitor mode
is_monitor_mode() {
    monitor_mode=$(iwconfig $1 2>/dev/null | grep "Mode:Monitor")
    if [ -n "$monitor_mode" ]; then
        return 0 # Device is in monitor mode
    else
        return 1 # Device is not in monitor mode
    fi
}

# Enumerate available network interfaces
interfaces=$(ip link show | grep '^[0-9]' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')

# Ask user which device to reset

echo "";
echo "Network Interface Reset Tool"
echo "===================================="
echo "Please select an interface to reset."
echo ""
echo "Available network interfaces:"
echo ""
select interface in $interfaces "Reset all devices" "Cancel"; do
    case $interface in
        "Reset all devices")
            for iface in $interfaces; do
                sudo ifconfig $iface down
                
                echo "Resetting $iface"
                if is_monitor_mode $iface; then
                    read -p "Device $iface is in monitor mode. Do you want to return it to managed mode? (y/n): " choice
                    if [ "$choice" = "y" ]; then
                        sudo iw dev $iface set type managed
                        echo "$iface returned to managed mode"
                    fi
                    sudo ifconfig $iface up
                fi
            done
            echo "All devices reset"
            break
            ;;
        "Cancel")
            echo "Operation canceled"
            exit
            ;;
        *)
            sudo ifconfig $interface down
            sudo ifconfig $interface up
            echo "Reset $interface"
            if is_monitor_mode $interface; then
                read -p "Device $interface is in monitor mode. Do you want to return it to managed mode? (y/n): " choice
                if [ "$choice" = "y" ]; then
                    sudo iw dev $interface set type managed
                    echo "$interface returned to managed mode"
                fi
            fi
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

# Ask if user wants to restart networking and NetworkManager
echo "Restart networking and NetworkManager?"
select option in "Restart networking and NetworkManager" "Start networking only" "Start NetworkManager only" "No, don't restart"; do
    case $option in
        "Restart networking and NetworkManager")
            sudo systemctl start networking
            sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
            echo "Networking Daemon and NetworkManager restarted"
            break
            ;;
        "Start networking only")
            sudo systemctl start networking
            echo "Networking restarted"
            break
            ;;
        "Start NetworkManager only")
            sudo systemctl restart Network-Manager
            echo "NetworkManager restarted"
            break
            ;;
        "No, don't restart")
            echo "Operation canceled"
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: What statement in the script gives "device busy" ?

Comment: if is_monitor_mode $iface; then
                    read -p "Device $iface is in monitor mode. Do you want to return it to managed mode? (y/n): " choice
                    if [ "$choice" = "y" ]; then
                        sudo iw dev $iface set type managed
                        echo "$iface returned to managed mode"
                    fi
                    sudo ifconfig $iface up
                fi

Comment: Could this an issue of monitor mode somehow blocking the device?

Comment: becaise I know that you can't make any changes to the interface without having to take the down

Comment: You need to initialize your array `interfaces=($(ip link show | grep '^[0-9]' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'))` then you can access the array as `${interfaces[@]}` where like `echo ${interfaces[1]}` will return something like `eno1` and where `echo ${interfaces[@]}` returns the entire array like `lo eno1`.  So, chances are your script is seeing the interface as a name like `lo eno1` right now and not the actual interface it is and that is why you are probably getting your error.

Comment: With the above, you can use something like `num_if=${#interfaces[@]}` that will give you a variable of `$num_if` that will return the number of interfaces detected in the system.

Comment: @Terrance tried that and script is working perfectly.  Thanks for the assist.